# Need help on a simple quiz with random answers

Tags: python

This is my code, why won't it work for me? It asks the questions but misses the `if` statement that I have created.

```
print("What is your name?")
name = input("")

import time
time.sleep(1)

print("Hello", name,(",Welcome to my quiz"))

import time
time.sleep(1)  

import random
ques = ['What is 2 times 2?', 'What is 10 times 7?', 'What is 6 times 2?']
print(random.choice(ques))

# Please note that these are nested IF statements

if ques == ('What is 2 times 2?'):
     print("What is the answer? ")
     ans = input("")


     if ans == '4':
         print("Correct")

     else:
         print("Incorrect")

elif ques == ('What is 10 times 7?'):
    print("What is the answer? ")
    ans = input("")

    if ans == '70':
         print("Correct")

    else:
        print("Incorrect")

elif ques == ('What is 6 times 2?'):
     print("What is the answer? ")
     ans = input("")

     if ans == '12':
          print("Correct")

     else:
         print("Incorrect")

import time
time.sleep(1)

import random
ques = ['What is 55 take away 20?', 'What is 60 devided by 2?', 'What is 500 take away 200']
print(random.choice(ques))


if ques == ('What is 55 take away 20?'):
   print("What is the answer? ")
   ans = input("")

   if ans == '35':
       print("Correct")

   else:
       print("Incorrect")

elif ques == ('What is 60 devided by 2?'):
     print("What is the answer? ")
     ans = input("")

     if ans == '30':
        print("Correct")

   else:
        print("Incorrect")

elif ques == ('What is 500 take away 200'):
    print("What is the answer? ")
    ans = input("")

    if ans == '300':
        print("Correct")

    else:
        print("Incorrect")
```

Comment: Why do you `import random` and `time` multiple times? What is the point of making a `random.choice` of the question if you then have to hard-code all of the answers?

Comment: And `import time` twice...

Comment: Not an answer, but: You should really try to make a function for all those questions, something like `def ask_question(num1, num2, operator)`, or if that's too hard, just `def ask_question(question, answer)`, so you don't have to repeat those lines over and over again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ques` is at all times still equal to the full list, not to a single element of the list.
If you want use this method, I suggest doing the following:

```
posedQuestion = random.choice(ques)
print(posedQuestion)
if posedQuestion == "First question":

elif ...
```

In addition you only need to do your imports once, so only one line saying `import time` will do ;)

Answer (score 1):

As well as the key error identified by MrHug, your code has the following problems:

1. Enormous amounts of unnecessary repetition;
2. Incorrect use of `import`;
3. Enormous amounts of unnecessary repetition;
4. A frankly bewildering attempt at string formatting; and
5. Enormous amounts of unnecessary repetition.

Note that the following code does what you are trying to do, but in a much more logical way:

```
# import once, at the top
import random

# use functions to reduce duplication
def ask_one(questions):
    question, answer = random.choice(questions):
    print(question)
    if input("") == answer:
        print("Correct")
    else:
        print("Incorrect")

# use proper string formatting
print("What is your name? ")
name = input("")
print("Hello {0}, welcome to my quiz".format(name))

# store related information together
ques = [('What is 2 times 2?', '4'),
        ('What is 10 times 7?', '70'),
        ('What is 6 times 2?', '12')]

ask_one(ques)
```

You could go further by storing the minimum information (i.e. the two numbers and the operator) in the list of `ques`, then formatting the question and calculating the outputs in the code itself.